# J2ME PHP Push Notification

Tags: php, java-me

I want to work on a project which has to do with the server sending notification to the client. The client side is a j2me application and the server side script will be implemented using PHP.

I have found out i can use the push registry API in midp 2.0 for push notifications, but i don't know how to implement this such that a socket connection will be created to the server such that notification can be sent to the client via the socket connection. The notification will then trigger the start of the midlet.

How can i use the push API to create a socket connection between client and server and have notifications sent to the client?

Answer (score 2):

Complete answer is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0417-push.html)

In short, there are two ways you might want to do it

1. Launch the application whenever you receive this "Push SMS"
2. Launch the application just the next time you receive this 'Push SMS"

For situation (1), you will need to specify this in JAD file. If you do this, the application manager will take necessary steps to launch your application the next time SMS is received.

For situation (2), you will need to write code:

```
PushRegistry.registerConnection("sms://<port number>","Midlet-Class","*");
```

The above note of mine would address the issue of launching the application upon incoming SMS. After you launch you can connect to your server and post data or retrieve data. This is a practical way of implementing push for J2ME platform.

But you seem to be wanting to launch the application on incoming network connection; this means you are creating a server socket on the phone and server is trying to establish the connection to the phone applications. I did work in such a situation where the phones were deployed on Motorola's iDen network (pre-2005 era). On such networks, it is possible to assign an IP address to the phone which makes the Push upon incoming network connection feasible. But that's past, on none of the GSM/CDMA networks, atleast at consumer's end, this cannot be supported. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things, One you need to listen one port number on the J2ME side for the incoming sms. Next you need to attach one GMS Modem to your computer system, Now send sms using this Modem on a particular port to the mobile you are listening. You can use AT Commands to send SMS.

Please visit this Nokia [Link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?92146-Receive-SMS-in-J2ME-application-from-GRPS-modem-%28AT-commands%29).